# Regex exact match of numbers: Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column filled with numbers and text. I want to find an exact combination of numbers i.e. 231

For e.g.

Not Ideal: Hello, the number is *231* but that's not what we want.
Ideal: Hello, the number is **231**-12342. Ah this is what I want
Ideal: Hello, the number is **231** 0000000. Ah this also I want.
Ideal: Hello, the number is **(231)**-0000000 also of interest.
Not Ideal: Hello, the number is 000*231*00000 is not what we want

Ideal output: Text 2,3,and 4.

Good Example:

[image]

Bad:

[image]

Comment: Text1 is also a solution to your problem. Text5 too ! English is not my natural language, but i think that writing 'which might be' is incorrect. Using 'must be' is certainly better. Can you please improve your sentence beginning with 'Ideally' ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions.

```
select *
from your_table
where instr(text_column, '231') > 0
```

But, then again, *all* examples you posted match. What's wrong with Text1's `231`? It has whitespaces arround it. Or Text5, which has "other characters" that surround it.

Comment: I do, because I am only looking for 231 and not 456**231**90. In the above instance both are a match.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what you said: "might be proceeded or succeeded by whitespace, and or any other characters."

Comment: That was an error on my part. I do apologize.

Comment: 231-XXXXX Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Good
000-000-2310 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Bad